# Search multiple results from database and display in single textbox

Tags: vb.net

guys i want to build an efficient searching tool in vb to search data from my database in mysql where i have stored paragraphs of some information. i want the search to return multiple results like google does but in a textbox in the form of 2-3 paragraphs of the same concept.Also to make the search more efficient i want to include the substring feature that is the % sign in the select query. can anyone tell me how to implement these two features ? here is my basic search code that returns just a single paragraph stored in the table into my result textbox that i hide first and then show when the results appear.

```
 If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter a Keyword")
    Else

        Dim conn As MySqlConnection
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;UserID=root;Password=admin674;Database=db1"
        Dim myadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        conn.Open()
        Dim sqlquery = "select text from text where name like '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
        Dim mycommand As New MySqlCommand
        mycommand.Connection = conn
        mycommand.CommandText = sqlquery
        myadapter.SelectCommand = mycommand
        Dim mydata As MySqlDataReader
        mydata = mycommand.ExecuteReader
        If mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Data Not Found")
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()

        Else
            mydata.Read()
            TextBox2.Text = mydata.Item("text")
            TextBox2.Show()


        End If
```

Comment: are you asking how to display multiple results in ONE textbox?  That's just `txtResults.Text &= mydata.Item("text")` as you loop thru results (a loop for multiple returns seems not to be implemented).  I dont follow what you want regarding substring and %, sorry

Comment: for the substring what i meant was that i had to type the exact keyword to search from the database so to remove that problem i needed a query to search substring so that the user doesnt have to type the exact keywords that are present in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already answered one question yourself - how to do a substring search, simple add % to your query:

```
Dim sqlquery = "select text from text where name like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

(ideally, instead of supplying search value in-line you would use [parametrized query](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html), which, among other things would help avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

As for the second part - you are already using DataReader, all you have to do is instead using a single `mydata.Read()` command -  loop thru all its results. Replace

```
mydata.Read()
TextBox2.Text = mydata.Item("text")
TextBox2.Show()
```

with

```
Dim sb as New StringBuilder()

While mydata.Read()
   sb.AppendLine(mydata("text"))
End While

TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString()
TextBox2.Show()
```

This approach uses [StringBuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) which is an efficient way to concatenate multiple strings.

P.S. Don't forget to close your DataReader and Connection after use.

Comment: thanks alot man it worked now the only thing is how can i  add spaces between those paragraphs that is they are all coming in a line so cant distinguish which one is which ? also can i use the same code to reutrn multiple images in a picture box too ?can you help with that thankx in advance

Comment: Yes you can add an extra space, just add an empty `sb.AppendLine()` command after the real one. And you can use similar code to return multiple images, but since a single picture box can show only one image - you will have to create picture boxes dynamically, add them to the form and populate with images in the loop.